# Android key naming convention

Tags: android, naming-conventions

Recently, I've found great [project and code guidelines](https://github.com/ribot/android-guidelines/blob/master/project_and_code_guidelines.md)
Here is paragraph [2.2.13](https://github.com/ribot/android-guidelines/blob/master/project_and_code_guidelines.md#2213-string-constants-naming-and-values) that gives us recommendations for keys naming. But I do not really understand the practical use of this naming. Why I can't simply use `KEY_` prefix for all of my keys in whole app?

Comment: You can use whatever you want. Those are just conventions and guidelines for that particular company.

Comment: @MikeM. But i think that they added those guidelines not just like "Wow, let's use that kind of naming". I think here is some kind of practical sense.

Comment: If you keep all of your keys within one java class file, I would imagine having a naming convention would be more helpful.  This also eliminates misuse or worse multi-purpose keys.

Comment: Yeah, it's for the same reason most use some kind of logic in variable naming: so it's easier to recall what a certain value means and relates to. I don't understand what the confusion is.

Comment: @eddiecubed @MikeM. confusion was caused by my inability to imagine in which case i can misuse key named like `KEY_`

Comment: I'm even do not understand what gives me the knowledge about which component of Android SDK this key is used in

Comment: The key they are referencing are key-value pairs within parcelable objects.  i.e. Bundles or extras for Intents.